# ruby refactor with block

Tags: ruby, refactoring, block

I want to refactor this code snippet as we can see a lot of duplication going around here. Can we use block refactoring to refactor the code given below.

```
module Jobs
  SendTrackEvent = Struct.new(:user_id, :event, :properties) do
    include A
    include B
    def perform
      @tracker ||= Tracker.new(Settings.key)
      @tracker.track(user_id, event, properties)
    end
  end

  SendAliasEvent = Struct.new(:new_distinct_id, :original_anonymous_id) do
    include A
    include B
    def perform
      @tracker ||= Tracker.new(Settings.key)
      @tracker.track(new_distinct_id, original_anonymous_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `:event` present `Struct.new(:new_distinct_id, :original_anonymous_id)` also ? I am not seeing it, but confirming twice

Comment: No :event is not present in the second one.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have found another stackexchange site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ in one of the comments. It might be better place for such question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This answer has been deleted for a while to see if it was the OP's sloppyness that made the code complicated; otherwise, a different solution would have been necessary. The OP has FINALLY (forty minutes after being pointed out, despite being online) made it clear, and fixed the question, so this answer is back again.

```
module Jobs
  def self.create_struct(*args) do
    Struct.new(*args) do
      include A
      include B
      def perform
        @tracker ||= Tracker.new(Settings.key)
        @tracker.track(*args.map{|sym| send(sym)})
      end
    end
  end
  SendTrackEvent = create_struct(:user_id, :event, :properties)
  SendAliasEvent = create_struct(:new_distinct_id, :original_anonymous_id)
end
```